# integration by integration by parts: $\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)$ (inner argument)

Tags: integration

Really simple integrale that can by solved much easier, but I wanna try straight integration by parts:

$\begin{array}{ccc}
&D&I \\
+&\cos(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)&\cos\frac{\pi}{L}\,x \\ \\
-&-\dfrac{L}{\pi}\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)& \dfrac{L}{\pi}\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)
\\\\\\
&\Rightarrow \int\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)
 =& \dfrac{L}{\pi}\cos(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)+\int\left(\dfrac{L}{\pi}\right)^2\sin\left((\frac{\pi}{L})\right)^2 \\\\ 
&&  \dfrac{L}{\pi}\cos(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)+\int\left(\dfrac{L}{\pi}\right)^2\left(1-\cos\left((\frac{\pi}{L})\right)^2\right)\\\\
&\Rightarrow 2\,\int\left(\dfrac{L}{\pi}\right)^2\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x) 
=&\dfrac{L}{\pi}\cos(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)-\left(\dfrac{L}{\pi}\right)^2\,x \\\\
&\Rightarrow \int\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x) = &\dfrac{\pi\,(\cos(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x))}{2\,L}-\dfrac{x}{2} \\\\
&\text{However, checking the integral gives:} \\\\
&\int\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x) = &\dfrac{L\,(\cos(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x))}{2\,\pi}-\dfrac{x}{2}\\\\
&\text{Where does the difference come from? } 
\end{array}$

Comment: $\int\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x) = \dfrac{L}{\pi}\cos(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x)\,\sin(\frac{\pi}{L}\,x) + \int\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)$

Comment: This is where you have a mistake. Once you fix that you get the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\int \cos^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) \ dx &= \frac{L}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) + \int \sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) \ dx \\
&= \frac{L}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) + \int\left(1-\cos^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)\right)\end{align*}
Therefore
$$2\int \cos^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) \ dx =\frac{L}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)+x$$

Comment: But where does the $\left(\dfrac{L}{\pi}\right)^2$ go? According to the D-I-method I have to multiply the last row and add as integral?

Comment: @Leon If we integrate $\cos(\frac{\pi x}{L})$ we get $\frac{L}{\pi}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{L})$ and if we differentiate $\cos(\frac{\pi x}{L})$ we get $-\frac{\pi}{L}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{L})$.

Comment: In other words, your expression for $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(\frac{\pi x}{L})$ is incorrect

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Thank you for pointing at that clumsiness. It really was messing with my head.